# While exporting report in excel using php, it works locally but not on the server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export a report using php. it will work fine in localhost but when I run it on the server it does not work and gives output like below.(All the variables which i have used that are not displaying here are declared as global so there is not an issue in variable declaration.) 
output:

[image]

Code I have tried is:

```
 $arrayissue = array();

            $count = 0;
            $screenshot_name = '';



            $cycle = $_SESSION['Cycle'];
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $query2 = "SELECT Cycle_name FROM cycle_master WHERE Cycle_id='$cycle'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
            $row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);


            $ews = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
            $ews->setCellValue('a1', 'This is the Result For : ' . $row12[0]);
            $rowCount = 2;



            $title = 'a1:aj1';
            $header = 'a2:aj2';

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($title)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('A9F5E1');

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($header)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');

            $style = array(
                'font' => array('bold' => true,),
                'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,),
            );

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($header)->applyFromArray($style);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(
                    'A2:' .
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() .
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()
            )->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
            $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $styleArray = array(
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => FALSE,
                    // 'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
                    'size' => 10,
                    'name' => 'Calibri'
            ));
            $limit = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
            echo $limit;
            for ($col = 'A'; $col != $limit; $col++) {

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setWidth(20);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
            }



            $queryforissue = "Select Issue_name from tmtool.project_issue_master where Project_id IN(Select Project_id from product_master Where Product_id='$productid')";
            $resultforissue = mysqli_query($conn, $queryforissue) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



            $countforissue = 0;
            $customeTitle = array();
            $customTitle1 = array('Execution ID', 'TC ID', 'Partner Name', 'Product Name', 'Test URL', 'Issue');
            $customTitle2 = array('Circle Name', 'Mobile Number', 'Date', 'Time', 'Screen Shot Name', 'Comment');
            while ($rowissue = mysqli_fetch_array($resultforissue)) {
                array_push($arrayissue, $rowissue['Issue_name']);
                $countforissue++;
            }


            $customTitle3 = array_merge($customTitle1, $arrayissue);
            $customTitle = array_merge($customTitle3, $customTitle2);


            $alph = 'A';
            foreach ($customTitle as $value) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alph . $rowCount, $value);
                $alph++;
            }
            $rowCount++;

            if ($startdate != '' && $enddate != '') {
                $queryresult = "SELECT testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,'_', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num ,testcase_master.`Testcase_title`,testcase_master.`Subscriber_type`,testcase_master.`Precondition`,testcase_master.`Activation_mode`,test_result_url.`Test_id`,test_result_url.`Assign_to`,test_result_url.`Circle_name`,test_result_url.`Performed_date`,test_result_url.`Status`,test_result_url.`Comment`,test_result_url.`Screen_shot_name`,test_result_url.`Device_used`,test_result_url.`Simcard_no`,test_result_url.`Time`,test_result_url.`Updated_date`,test_result_url.`Updated_time`,test_result_url.`Updated_by`  FROM tmtool.test_result_url LEFT JOIN tmtool.testcase_master  ON test_result_url.`Testcase_id`=testcase_master.`Testcase_id` WHERE testcase_master.`Product_id` = '$productid' AND (test_result_url.`Performed_date` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') AND testcase_master.`Testcase_id` IN (SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase WHERE Testsuite_id IN (SELECT Testsuite_id FROM testsuite_master WHERE Cycle_id = '$cycle')) order by num";
            } else {
                $queryresult = "SELECT testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,'_', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num ,testcase_master.`Testcase_title`,testcase_master.`Subscriber_type`,testcase_master.`Precondition`,testcase_master.`Activation_mode`,test_result_url.`Test_id`,test_result_url.`Assign_to`,test_result_url.`Circle_name`,test_result_url.`Performed_date`,test_result_url.`Status`,test_result_url.`Comment`,test_result_url.`Screen_shot_name`,test_result_url.`Device_used`,test_result_url.`Simcard_no`,test_result_url.`Time`,test_result_url.`Updated_date`,test_result_url.`Updated_time`,test_result_url.`Updated_by`  FROM tmtool.test_result_url LEFT JOIN tmtool.testcase_master  ON test_result_url.`Testcase_id`=testcase_master.`Testcase_id` WHERE testcase_master.`Product_id` = '$productid' AND testcase_master.`Testcase_id` IN (SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase WHERE Testsuite_id IN (SELECT Testsuite_id FROM testsuite_master WHERE Cycle_id = '$cycle')) order by num";
            }



            $resultquery = mysqli_query($conn, $queryresult) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultquery)) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $row['Test_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $row['Testcase_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $row['Precondition']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $rowCount, $row['Activation_mode']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E' . $rowCount, $row['Testcase_title']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F' . $rowCount, $row['Status']);


                for ($i = 0, $alpha2 = 'G'; $i < $countforissue; $i++, $alpha2++) {

                    $querygetResult = "Select $arrayissue[$i] from test_result_url where Test_id='$row[Test_id]'";
                    $getResult = mysqli_query($conn, $querygetResult) or die('Error querying database');
                    $rowResult = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult);

                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $rowResult[0]);
                }

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Circle_name']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Simcard_no']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Performed_date']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Time']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Screen_shot_name']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Comment']);


                $rowCount++;
            }

            unset($alpha2);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Product Wise");
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="TestResults.xlsx"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            ob_end_clean();
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: what is the output. do you get any errors? try to set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very top of your file.

Comment: I have attached image of output please check it

Comment: Do you have write permission on the folder in the server? Try chmod to change it.

Comment: I would suggest that you're sending something else to the browser before the Excel file (possibly the letter "A"), so PHP is already sending normal headers.... I'd expect your logs to contain a number of warnings about headers already sent

Answer (score 1):

Found Answer for myself.

1) There is an echo statement is there which sends 'A' to header.so remove echo
2) ob_end_clean() is creating problem when i have removed that code its work fine.

Thanks all who have tried to help me.